# Gstreamer cannot find internal camera on a Mac

Tags: macos, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I have installed Gstreamer via homebrew on my mac. I want to stream the mac's internal camera's footage, however when I run
`gst-device-monitor-1.0` I keep getting `Probing devices... Failed to start device monitor!`

I also tried running the same command with `GST_DEBUG=2` and then I get

```
WARN devicemonitor gstdevicemonitor.c:501:gst_device_monitor_start:<devicemonitor0> No filters have been set, will expose all devices found
0:00:00.002759000 24294 0x7ffc5151c190 WARN devicemonitor gstdevicemonitor.c:507:gst_device_monitor_start:<devicemonitor0> No providers match the current filters
```

The version I'm running is

```
gst-device-monitor-1.0 version 1.20.0
GStreamer 1.20.0
```

How do I get this to work? I have checked the mac settings and I don't see anything that'd block this. How do I make gstreamer see my mac's internal camera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem on my Mac (M1, macOS Monterey). It is issue of gst-device-monitor-1.0. According to its [source code](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/blob/main/subprojects/gstreamer/gst/gstdevicemonitor.c#L499) it cannot find any corresponding device providers:

```
  if (monitor->priv->filters->len == 0) {
    GST_WARNING_OBJECT (monitor, "No filters have been set, will expose all "
        "devices found");
    gst_device_monitor_add_filter_unlocked (monitor, NULL, NULL);
  }

  if (monitor->priv->providers->len == 0) {
    GST_OBJECT_UNLOCK (monitor);
    GST_WARNING_OBJECT (monitor, "No providers match the current filters");
    return FALSE;
  }
```

The problem appeared a year ago and has not yet been resolved:
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-base/-/issues/780
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/issues/667

Still gstreamer itself can access video (including mac's internal camera) and audio sources on macOS just fine.

Video:

```
gst-launch-1.0 avfvideosrc device-index=0 ! video/x-raw, framerate=30/1, width=1280, height=720 ! queue ! autovideosink
```

Audio:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v osxaudiosrc device=0 ! audio/x-raw ! queue ! autoaudiosink
```

Note: `avfvideosrc` is part of `gst-plugins-bad`, `osxaudiosrc` - part of `gst-plugins-good`

Comment: Fair enough. I checked and gstreamer indeed could access the camera and stream footage. I accept your answer. Thanks a lot for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

```
export GST_PLUGIN_PATH=/opt/homebrew/lib/gstreamer-1.0/
```

Setting this works for me.

Comment: This certainly changed things for me, too. Setting the GST_PLUGIN_PATH, as described, allowed `gst-device-monitor-1.0` to find some devices on my M1 MacBook Pro. It only found the mic and speakers, however. I installed GStreamer via HomeBrew, so perhaps I need to add some missing plug-ins, etc.

edit: Yep... I needed to add `gst-plugins-bad` now I get the desired output, including the FaceTime HD camera.